# I created 3 tables users, meeting and request how to get the users who requested a meeting?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I Created 3 tables: users, meetings and requests which has relation with both tables, for the page meeting/3 meeting with the id 3, i want to show all the users who submitted a request in request table:

User:
    users
    id
    name

Meeting:
    meeting
    id
    name

Requests: 
    requests
    id
    meeting_id
    request_id

```
$requests = App\Requests::all();
                            foreach ($requests as $request)
                            {
                                $user = App\User::where('id', $request->user_id)->first();
                                echo $user->name . '<br>';
                            }
```

this shows the user but not filtered by meeting id

How to get users from meeting page where there is record in requests table?

Comment: Use [Manu to Many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, correct me if I'm wrong.
You want to retrieve from db all the user requests for the meeting with id = 3.

Try with:

```
$requests = App\Requests::where('meeting_id', 3)->get();
foreach($requests as $request){
    echo $request->user->name;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

and in your models you should setup some relations like:

in your user model:

```
public function requests(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Request');
}
```

in your request model:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

---

You can also do something like:

```
$meeting = App\Meeting::find(3);
$users = $meeting->users;
```

This will allow you, if you setup properly relations between models, to retrieve directly the users that have submitted a request for that meeting.

check laravel's docs about relations: [laravel relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Worked, but looks like you are good, please tell me how to do this: users can create meetings and for each meeting page i want to display the users who applied for this meeting, in the requests table there is a column called accepted 1 is accepted and 0 is not, so this worked so far for users data: name, image, etc, but i want to show from requests table the column accepted, basically i want to show all the users who applied to a meeting and there status if they are accepted, thanks alot

Comment: Glad it worked. Okay then, you have just to modify the initial query on requests applying antoher filter like:
`$requests = App\Requests::where('meeting_id', 3)->where('accepted', 1)->get();`

This will retrieve all the requests for meeting with id = 3 and have accepted = 1. The flow remains unchanged.

However, i think you should check the laravel documentation about querying the database. It is dead simple with query builder... have a look [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#introduction)

Comment: I want to check if there is a request row: user has applied to a meeting, this is the code for RequestController
$meeting = Meeting::find($id);
     $request = Requests::where('meeting_id', 2)->first();
if(!Requests::where('meeting_id', $meeting->id)->exists() && $request->user_id == Auth::user()->id)
     {
      // dd('Invitation exists!');
      $request = new Requests();
      $request->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
      $request->meeting_id = $meeting->id;
      $request->save();
      return redirect('meeting');
     }

Comment: Can't you simply do something like:
`$currentUserRequest = Request::where('meeting_id', 2)->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();`
`if($currentUserRequest){
//request exists
}else{
//request does not exists
}`

Comment: Now I can create and join meetings, other user also, but I can accept only meetings I created,
public function accept($id)
    {
     $meeting = Meeting::find($id);
     $request = Requests::where('meeting_id', $meeting->id)->first();
     $request->accepted = 1;
     $request->save();
     return Redirect::back();
    }
how can I make the code work so the logged user who created the meeting can accept requests from users to join meetings created by him?

Comment: dude, this is basic coding :/ you've got all the tools you just have to be more independent. Anyway, you just have to check on the MeetingController who is the current loggedUser. For example: `if(Auth::user()->id == $meeting->owner->id) { //the current logged user is the owner, show attending user list} else {//is not the owner, show form with accept or decline meeting presence }`. --- properly add to the 'meeting' table a column and track the 'creator_id' filling it with the user_id of the user who created the meeting.

Comment: In addition: properly add to the 'meeting' table a column and track the 'creator_id' filling it with the user_id of the user who created the meeting. In meeting model add a relationship 'belongsTo' and link it to user model via 'creator_id'. check docs : [Auth](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user) and [define relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

Comment: I have checked the meeting owner, but when i send a request for accepting meetings, the user can only accept requests to join his meetings, dummyuser has the meeting dummymeeting, when you access meeting dummymeeting, dummy user can only accept dummyuser join request, there are other requests but the meeting owner cant accept the join request

Answer (score 0):

I will assume `request_id` in `reuqests` table as a foreign key from users table.

The query should be.

```
select u.users from users as u inner join requests as r on u.id=r.request_id where r.meeting_id=3;
```

This query joins the two tables (`users` and `requests`) and fetches results for the given `meeting_id`.

Answer (score 0):

$requests = App\Requests::where('meeting_id', 3)->get();

```
foreach($requests as $request){
    echo $request->user->name;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $request->accepted;
    echo '<br>';
}
```